# Issue with grant for OAuth2 authentication with google

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, grant-oauth

I am using [Grant](https://github.com/simov/grant) for OAuth2 authentication with google. I supplied all the parameters in the config.json :

```
  {
    "server": {
    "protocol": "https",
    "host": "thooslo-com-shaunakde.c9.io"
  },
  "google":{
    "authorize_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "access_url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "oauth": 2,
    "custom_parameters": ["access_type"],
    "scope_delimiter":" ",
    "scope":["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
    "client_id":"39109025743-veaeooi4v9ooirabeseujn8u2ohjbqf7.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "client_secret":"DO8ozwoFqtP654jzi-wPQF10",
    "callback": "/users"
  }
  }
```

But it still refuses to send all the parameters. I get a "client_id" not sent error.

I modified the library to print out the URL and this is indeed the case:

```
Starting child process with 'node ./bin/www'
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fthooslo-com-shaunakde.c9.io%2Fconnect%2Fgoogle%2Fcallback&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fyoutube%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive
GET /connect/google 302 26.492 ms - 574
```

I did manage to get the first step to work once, by some permutation, but then it failed on client_secret not found.

Is there something I am doing wrong? The library seems to be non buggy.

Comment: The issue was resolved here - https://github.com/simov/grant/issues/18

Comment: @simo please submit it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sufficient to have this configuration

```
{
    "server": {
    "protocol": "https",
    "host": "thooslo-com-shaunakde.c9.io"
  },
  "google":{
    "key":"39109025743-veaeooi4v9ooirabeseujn8u2ohjbqf7.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "secret":"DO8ozwoFqtP654jzi-wPQF10",
    "scope":[
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
    ],
    "callback": "/users"
  }
}
```